# Extracting from tuples with list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples:

```
tuples = [(0,1), (2,0), (3,4), (1,2) etc. ]
```

And I want to create another list with all the numbers that have been paired with a 0. I tried doing this with a list comprehension:

```
relations = [x[1] if x[0] == 0 else x[0] if x[1] == 0 for x in tuples]
```

However, this gives an error. Python doesn't seem to like 'x' being a tuple. Can "relations" be defined with list comprehension or do I need write out longer code?

Comment: Although this can be written as a list comprehension I think this is a case where a usual `for` loop or a separate function (called in the list comprehension) would be more comprehensible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need one more `else`; each conditional expression needs *both* an `if` and an `else`, you are omitting the `else` from the second conditional expression.

But your problem can be expressed much more simply as:

```
relations = [x[0] or x[1] for x in tuples if 0 in x]
```

This first filters on any tuple that has a zero in it, then picks the value that is not 0.

Demo:

```
>>> tuples = [(0,1), (2,0), (3,4), (1,2)]
>>> [x[0] or x[1] for x in tuples if 0 in x]
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

Ternary expressions need an else condition, that's why you're getting that error.

```
>>> [x[0] if x[1] ==0 else x[1] for  x in  tuples if 0 in x]
[1, 2]
```